# Can I create an object that can be used for more than one connection in different clients?

Tags: php

I usually code in c# and python for desktop and the problem I am having with PHP is that I'm not sure how to do X things without having an object from a class I create where I can set X attributes and retrieve them when needed.

As an example, if I do need to have a page that displays a message until something is sent as post, what I would do is use an object and change the attribute but I can't because a new object is created on each connection if I do use DBs I will have problems because I will have a connection to that site every time and it will overload my DB.

Is there any way to make this on PHP?

Comment: Depending on the database you are using the API for that database might support persistent connections. However you usually don't use persistent connections, do you actually have problems with "too many" short living connections to your database and if yes, what are the problems you have?

Comment: I have done apps that due to requesting too much to DBs  (not in local)  had taken down a phpmyadmin with its db. How would I implement a persistent connection?

Comment: That depends on the database and the API you are using. [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) has a flag to request a persistent connections, however the underlying API/database must support it somehow.

Comment: How can I check the different APIs? on my cpanel

Comment: Usually some form of connection pooling is enabled on the server whereby open connections to the database are kept in memory, and then allocated to a process whenever it requests to open a connection. The code then re-uses available connections which is more efficient than constantly opening and closing them. So you don't have to do anything much different in your code to use that - there might be a setting but that's about it.

Comment: @KevinPita You can use `phpinfo();` to see which libraries are enabled in your PHP installation and which APIs you can use. Then check the documentations of these APIs to see what they can do and if they (and the database) support persistent connections.

Comment: If you've written code in the past which had overloaded your database server (and are you sure it was definitely that which was the bottleneck and not some other component?) there could be many reasons for that - inadequate hardware to cope with usage volumes, inefficient queries, unnecessary queries, poor schema design, network latency, the list goes on.  But in general, all web apps have this same design where you open (or get hold of) a DB connection every time a new request is processed. It's generally not a problem directly, it's just the way it is because the web is stateless.